# Programmatic Bokeh Server

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh. I am trying to run a Bokeh server programatically which is started within a `PyQt` application.

This article http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2017/06/28/simple-bokeh-server describes how to do this, but it requires using python notebook, since the Tornado web server piggybacks on Jupyter notebook’s own IOLoop.

I do not want to use Jupyter notebook, but I want to run it so it "piggybacks on PyQt's io loop".

I have tried running the server as its standalone Thread, but it does not work (accessing the website `localhost:5001` just hangs saying "waiting for localhost").

Here is how the thread I currently have. It is called from a QThreadPool within my main `PyQt` application when a user clicks a button.

```
class Streamer(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Streamer, self).__init__()

    def update(self):
        new = {'x': [random.random()],
               'y': [random.random()],
               'color': [random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])]}
        self.source.stream(new)

    def make_document(self, doc):
        self.source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [], 'y': [], 'color': []})
        doc.add_periodic_callback(self.update, 100)

        self.fig = figure(title='Streaming Circle Plot!', sizing_mode='scale_width',
                     x_range=[0, 1], y_range=[0, 1])
        self.fig.circle(source=self.source, x='x', y='y', color='color', size=10)

        doc.title = "Now with live updating!"
        doc.add_root(self.fig)

    def run(self):
        self.apps = {'/': Application(FunctionHandler(self.make_document))}
        server = Server(self.apps, port=5001)
        server.start()
        server.show('/')
        while True:
            QtCore.QThread.sleep(1)
```

**EDIT**:

I tried using `server.run_until_shutdown()` instead of `server.start()` but I get an error saying

> signal only works in main thread

But I cannot run the bokeh server in my main thread since it hangs my GUI application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one way to get around this.

Using `server.start()` does not start the `tornado` webserver, so nothing will happen in the initial approach. On the other hand, looking at the code for `server.run_until_shutdown()` generates a system signal before running the `tornado` IOLoop`, which would not work if the server is running on a thread.

I found an example in `bokeh` repository, and linked from the [docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library), where the `torando` server can be started manually in a blocking call on the thread (no signals required). Here the code which should go in the `run` method of the thread:

```
def run(self):
  server = Server({'/': self.make_document})
  server.start()

  server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
  server.io_loop.start()
```

Comment: Have also a look at the [examples](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/server_embed), this one and others